# How to max from column using dynamic column name 'Select MAX(@variable) from table' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to get `MAX` of an `int` column, but my column is looping in variable.

I have tried this

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Declare @gender nvarchar(10)
Declare @max int
Declare @col int

set @col = 'UserId'
set @gender='0'
set @sql = 'Select @max  = MAX(@col) From CustomerTbl Where Gender=@gender'

print @sql

Execute sp_executesql  @sql , N'@gender nvarchar(10), @count int OUTPUT ,@col int',@gender,@max OUTPUT,@col
sELECT @max`
```

I want the max of each or current column in variable @max but I am getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UserId' to data type int.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `@col` variable as `int`, but you are trying to set `'UserId'` text. This obviously can't happen.

Set column name (`UserId`) when you construct your dynamic query:

```
set @sql = 'Select @max  = MAX(UserId) From CustomerTbl Where Gender=@gender'
```

If you get the column name run-time, then change the type of the `@col` variable to `nvarchar(128)` and don't use parameter, but concatenate it:

```
set @sql = 'Select @max  = MAX(' + @col + ') From CustomerTbl Where Gender=@gender'
```

Comment: @user `set @sql = 'Select  @max   = MAX(' + @col + ') From CustomerTbl Where Gender=@gender' ` error showing  |Must declare the scalar variable "@max".| when I concatenate @max var too error changes to |Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select ' to data type int.|

Comment: You forgot to declare `@max` in the parameters list passed to `sp_executesql`. Currently it is `N'@gender nvarchar(10), @count int OUTPUT ,@col int'`. You don't need `@col`, so change it to: `N'@gender nvarchar(10), @count int OUTPUT ,@max int OUTPUT'`. I do not see where you use `@count` either, so if this is the whole statement, you can remove it too.